# The First call REST after start Tomcat is very slow

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jersey

My Rest service is working well at all, but when im starting Tomcat server and call first Rest then it's realize like 3-4 second. Another call Rest is fast like 2-30ms. 
I'm think that is because in the first call im login to database or starting transaction (EntityManager). [Right?]

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>AggregatorGroupRest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.agg.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="EmployeeService">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>    
    <class>com.agg.atomic.model.Employee</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
            <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"    value="jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/qwqwqwqw?useSSL=false" />       
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="login" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
                <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
                <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My implementation of Rest

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService{

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public EmployeeModel getEmployee() {
        TestBuilder testBuilder = new TestBuilder();
        return testBuilder.getEmployee();
    }
}
```

Builder:

```
public class TestBuilder {
    private static EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();

    public EmployeeModel getEmployee(){
        if (!entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        Employee employee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, 6);

        EmployeeModel result = TestResultMapping.getEmployee(employee);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And implementation EntityManager:

```
public class EntityManagerUtil {
    private static final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    static {
        try {
            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EmployeeService");
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

And now question:
What i can do that my first call REST will fast like others after him.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're setting up your entity manager to open up connections directly. You might have better results if you use a server managed datasource which will have a connection pool so you can force X connections to be already available in the pool right from the start

Comment: Thanks for comment. Cen u show me how i can implement that server managed datasource in my code?

Comment: No, I'm probably all the way on the other side of the planet. You're better off just researching the keywords and finding out for yourself, that's part of the job.

Comment: If Tomcat redeploys your web application on startup, that would explain why the first call is slow. Try to make that first call without restarting Tomcat and see it's still slow. I don't that using a JNDI dana source will help in this case though it certainly makes sense to use a connection pool.

Comment: @dsp_user : Im starting aplication associated to Tomcat from Eclipse so what can i call first call without restarting server? When first rest coming this deploy in console: [EL Info]: connection: 2016-03-15 13:40:39.031--ServerSession(470550036)--/file:/D:/path...path/WEB-INF/classes/_EmployeeService login successful

Comment: Just issue a http request (calling your first service) via a web browser while Tomcat and your web app is running (e.g. http://localhost:8080/your_web_service/some_action).  You don't have to use Eclipse for this (although it will probably be running because you're probably started Tomcat from Eclipse)

Comment: @dsp_user : Thanks for this information. Im requesting fom SoupUI app (But im think is that same like web browser). So how i can resolve this issue? Just starting tomcat without Eclipse? And run webapp as what? Sorry im little new in javaee.

Comment: Can you give me the URL to your web service? Now if this is a post http request, then you'll probably have to mock it in either SoapUI or Eclipse. I've only used SoapUI for SOAP web services (generating a http request from a wsdl)

Comment: its a simple: http://localhost:8080/AggregatorGroupRest/test

Comment: If it's a HTTP GET request, then just copy that address in your web browser (provided that there are no arguments). The response (json or xml) should appear in the browser (I assume that Jersey  sends a http compliant mime type response).

Comment: Yes this is only GET without arguments. Its only test rest with two field from database which has only one column :). Im trying this in web browser and response that two field correctly but first call still slow. When im refresh then is fast.

Comment: Try to reach a missing page to obtain a 404 and check if you also obtain the delay at the first request.